# I can't set an image for background using css

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, background-image

I have a laravel 5 project where I want to set and custom an image as background, but I simply can't. I can set the background to a color - that works fine, but not when I'm using an image...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>
    body{
        background: url("/resources/assets/images/anders.png") no-repeat;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prolly your url path is no good :)

Comment: I use phpstorm and it suggest the path for the image "anders.png".

Comment: What browser are you using ?

Comment: I use chrome @NenadVracar

Comment: try <img src="/resources/assets/images/anders.png"/> inside the body to make sure the url is good or not

Comment: but when i past this url: http://localhost:8888/OpiioApp/resources/assets/images/anders.png is works. But I don't understand how to set the path so it used the whole url? because later i want to upload this source code to a webhosting service

Comment: May i ask why don't you put that css in one separate css file?

Comment: I would do that - I just have it in one file till it works as i want it to and move it over to a seperated file after. It is easier not to move around files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root the url to the site using . before the resource.

```
body{
    background: url("./resources/assets/images/anders.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @benni_mac_b but it did not work. But i do the same to include my css file and it works... <link href="../resources/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">